# How to extract sound of unity game from apk?

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine

I previously developed a unity game many years ago.

Now I have lost my project and I only have an apk.
To say in short, in my new game I need some audio files from that game. I have extracted the apk but strangely I haven't found any audio formatted file in the asset!

So what are the formats of unity audio assets?!
and how can I extract and change them to common formats like .ogg or .mp3?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Unity Assets Explorer.
http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10085

Comment: Still can't find audio files,but it was a nice tool.
maybe should trying some other solutions ,like record them from previous game with a internally sound recorder to get high quality sounds.
So Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution(stop searching more although, you maybe find something on more googling)

But for those who have same requirement, I did it by an android application that work only on rooted devices, which can record sounds internally.

Hope to help:)